# Trying to develop gatsby and encountering error

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, development-environment

I used to use gatsby and it would develop perfectly fine, but recently my react app and gatsby have not been working. I have been able to skip the errors in react app by adding a line of code to my .env files, but for gatsby, I am getting the following output when I type gatsby develop in the terminal:

```
Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use gatsby build
⠀
success Building development bundle - 3.763s
success Re-building development bundle - 0.054s

 ERROR 

Source and destination must not be the same.



  Error: Source and destination must not be the same.
  
  - stat.js:80 
    [gatsby-tutorial]/[fs-extra]/lib/util/stat.js:80:17
  
  - stat.js:38 
    [gatsby-tutorial]/[fs-extra]/lib/util/stat.js:38:16
  
  - polyfills.js:295 callback
    [gatsby-tutorial]/[graceful-fs]/polyfills.js:295:20
```

When I run gatsby info --clipboard in my project directory, I get:

```
System:
    OS: macOS 10.15.3
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770HQ CPU @ 2.20GHz
    Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.18.1 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.4 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.14.7 - /usr/local/bin/npm
  Languages:
    Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 84.0.4147.105
    Firefox: 78.0.2
    Safari: 13.0.5
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: ^2.23.12 => 2.23.12
  npmGlobalPackages:
    gatsby-cli: 2.12.68
```

I am running gatsby develop in visual studio code so I am in the correct project directory, but I am still confused about why I am getting this error. I could add the react app error if that would help anyone figure out the problem with gatsby.

Comment: Why do you assume that you are on the correct path because you are in VSCode? What's this path?

Comment: I started back from the home directory and then tried to then run gatsby develop and still got the same error.

Comment: So, do you run `gatsby develop` in the root of the project?

Comment: yeah, I was at the root of the project and it came with the same error.